# How to remove <a> tags that contain hashtags in their text?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, hashtag

I want to delete the **linked hashtags**

I do not want to delete hashtags without links.

I do not want to delete other links.

For example:

```
<p><a href="/user/username" >Username</a> #filmphotography #vintage <a href="/tag/travelgram" >#travelgram</a> #montreux #royalpalacehotel <a href="/tag/switzerland">#switzerland</a> #selfie <a href="/tag/meandmysister">#meandmysister</a></p>
```

I want to be:

```
<p><a href="/user/username" >Username</a> #filmphotography #vintage  #montreux #royalpalacehotel #selfie </p>
```

This code doesn't work:

```
$html = preg_replace('#<a(.*?)>#(.*?)</a>#is', '', $html);
```

Comment: don't parse html/xml with regex ... just don't

Comment: Your code can't work. There is no hashtag in front of your link and no `#is` afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer using character set instead of quantifier

```
 <a[^>]*>#[^<#]*<\/a>
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sQVBs6/6)

it is more efficient because can't backtrack, and avoids backtracking unwanted results.

`(.*?)` lazy quantifier means the shortest match but in case of backtracking it will contain bigger match because starting too early.

in case of unexpected matches regex may be improved.

Comment: As you mentioned in your last line, this regex pattern needs to be improved because it can break when two hashtags exist in a single `<a>`.  Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bff8596cd9f5bc786b37360766c9c1136ce07063  And you could fix it, then I could suggest that an `<a>` tag might contain `<` and break the script again.  This is why regex should not be used. As Roman commented, regex is not the way.

Comment: i let the OP confirm, if that the case can be easily changed to `<a[^>]*>#[^<]*<\/a>` but as it may match more, the OP has to explain more what must match and not

Comment: My point is regex patterns can be broken.  A tag with `<` in the text or `>` in an attribute will foul things up.  I'm not starting a war, just stating facts about the dangers of parsing html with regex.

Comment: indeed, it depends on the use case and regex engine, that's why i said short answer, however regex engines like pcre can handle xml without any problem but it requires more experience.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by rollstuhlfahrer, you have made the folly of using an unescaped character that is also the pattern delimiter.  The easiest way to solve this is to change the delimiters to a valid delimiting character that is not used in the pattern itself (e.g. `~`).

Your new pattern will look like this: `~<a(.*?)>#(.*?)</a>~is`

But there is more bad news...

Your output will be this:

```
<p> #montreux #royalpalacehotel  #selfie </p>
```

The regex engine is trying to make you happy and it does its best to find matches for you.  In doing so, it keeps extending its search beyond your intended qualifying tags and gobbles up non-qualifying tags too!

---

Here is the good news: **DomDocument for the win!**

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be71f4465a31a626ba7088fe2b8800afae7deb75))

```
$html='<p><a href="/user/username" >Username</a> #filmphotography #vintage <a href="/tag/travelgram" >#travelgram</a> #montreux #royalpalacehotel <a href="/tag/switzerland">#switzerland</a> #selfie <a href="/tag/meandmysister">#meandmysister</a></p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); // 2nd params to remove DOCTYPE);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a){
    if(strpos($a->nodeValue,'#')===0){
        $remove[]=$a;
    }
} 
foreach($remove as $bad_a){
    $bad_a->parentNode->removeChild($bad_a); 
}     
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<p><a href="/user/username">Username</a> #filmphotography #vintage  #montreux #royalpalacehotel  #selfie </p>
```

This trick is (and this hung me up for a little while, until the solution found me here: http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php#90292 )

**You must use two loops to remove the tags.** The first to generate a list of tags to remove, then a second to do the removal.